# Creating "yes" and "no" radio buttons using struts2 and freemarker

Tags: struts2, freemarker

In my struts2 application I'd like to bind a boolean property (lets call it frobbed with an isFrobbed() getter)  on my controller to a pair of "yes" and "no" radio buttons (I know that I could use a checkbox, but for various reasons we would prefer an explicit "yes" and "no").

With a checkbox, I'd do something along the lines of this:

```
 <@s.checkbox name="frobbed" label="would you like this to be frobbed?" />
```

However, with radio buttons I am totally lost.   I know there's a struts2 tag named "radio"  but I'm not sure how it's used.   For example, this doesn't work.

```
<@s.radio name="frobbed"  value="true"  label="Please frob this object" />
<@s.radio name="frobbed"  value="false" label="No frobbing, thanks." />
```

I'd like this to be bound to the value of 'frobbed' in the controller so that, for example, when the value is true the "yes" radiobutton is automatically selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax works with FreeMarker for a boolean choice:

```
<@s.radio label="" name="frob" list="#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{true:'Frob it',false:'Leave unfrobbed'}" />
```

Comment: It works! But... how?  I didn't even know there was a literal that instantiates/initializes an object like LinkedHashMap.  Could you send me a link to the chapter of the documentation that covers this?  I couldn't find it anywhere at http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html.    Thanks again!

Comment: The online documentation I've discovered so far isn't the clearest on this topic, but what is contained in the list attribute value is an OGNL expression.   Apache OGNL docs have some info on expressions involving maps here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html

Comment: awesome :D just what I needed

Answer (score 2):

When the choice is a simple Yes/No, True/False - I prefer to define the choices in-situ within the jsp. Something like ..

```
<s:radio label="Frobbed?" list="#{true:'Frob Me',false:'Leave me Frobless'}" name="frobbed" value="%{frobbed}"></s:radio>
```

Regards

Comment: Agreed; for short, unchanging things that don't need any testing, this is easier.

Comment: I like the idea of doing it this way, but I wasn't able to get it to work w/ freemarker syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the `<s:radio>` tag is used with a list of options (or a map). For example, with a map, the key would be the radio values (like `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` in this case) and the value would be the radio button label ("Frob away", "I choose to remain frobbedless").

```
<s:radio list="yesNo" name="frobbed"/>
```

The `yesNo` attribute value is that list or map.

(With a list you'd expose an object with the label and value and use the "listKey" and "listValue" `<s:radio>` attributes. (IIRC))

Comment: I think this would work, but I like the idea of defining the hashmap on the fly (as suggested in another answer).   Any idea how what the syntax for that is in freemarker?

Comment: Probably something like `list="%{{key: value, ...}}"`, first the FM markup, then the OGNL, but I'd have to test it.

Comment: FYI - no dice on that ftl format, but getting the hash from the controller works so I'll roll w/ that for now.  Thanks!

Comment: @NobodyMan No sweat; let me check the syntax on that.

Comment: @NobodyMan I couldn't figure out how to get FM and OGNL syntax to play nice together; it may well be a limitation of FM itself, or how OGNL chooses to evaluate an FM expression/variable.